# Loop action in Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa

How I can loop some action in Cocoa? For example I want that random numbers change in textField every 1 sec.

Comment: Xcode is just an IDE - you mean Objective-C/Cocoa presumably ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example:

```
 -(void)awakeFromNib {

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(changeTextFieldsInt:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
}

- (void)changeTextFieldsInt:(NSTimer *)time {
     [textField setIntValue:rand()];
}
```

Don't forget IBoutlet textField.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to look at the [`NSTimer` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html).